# Unpredicatable alarm__ignore signal

Tags: linux, perl, signals, centos

I keep getting an "`alarm__ignore`" signal when executing the below foreach loop.  Curiously, the error appears on different iterations of the loop (ie, sometimes the third time through, sometimes the 26th, etc.) and I can't identify any rhyme or reason to when it occurs.  This script runs without an error when I comment out "`my @cols = split(/\s+/, $line)`," but I can't figure out why a split would cause the signal.

Here is the code:

```
my @forest = ();

foreach (@treeBlobs) {

    my @treeBlob = @{$_};

    my $thisTree = eval {

        my %tree = ();

        foreach my $line (@treeBlob) {
            my @cols = split(/\s+/, $line);
            $tree{id++} = {map{$CLASSIFIER_COLUMNS[$_] => $cols[$_]}(0..scalar @cols-1)};
        }

        return \%tree;

    };

    print "ERROR: $@\n" if $@; 
    push @forest, $thisTree;
    my $sc = scalar @forest;
    print "FOREST: $sc; $thisTree\n";
}
```

And here is some sample output:

```
...
FOREST: 19; HASH(0x4668c90)
FOREST: 20; HASH(0x4664e10)
FOREST: 21; HASH(0x4658e30)
FOREST: 22; HASH(0x465ca80)
FOREST: 23; HASH(0x4664860)
FOREST: 24; HASH(0x4664240)
FOREST: 25; HASH(0x46740b0)
FOREST: 26; HASH(0x4667a70)
FOREST: 27; HASH(0x465cf50)
FOREST: 28; HASH(0x465cfd0)
ERROR: __alarm__ignore__(54)

FOREST: 29;
FOREST: 30; HASH(0x465ada0)
```

Again, the error does not always (or even usually) occur in the 29th iteration of the loop - it can happen in any iteration.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Currently this code is useless. Provide input data for `@treeBlobs` and `@CLASSIFIER_COLUMNS`, which Perl distro/version and which CentOS you are running. There's also a syntax mistake with the hash key `id++`.

Comment: That exception is thrown by [Mail::SpamAssassin::Timeout](http://p3rl.org/Mail::SpamAssassin::Timeout). Is something in your code using that?

Comment: my @CLASSIFIER_COLUMNS = qw(node_id left_daughter right_daughter split_var split_point status prediction);

Comment: @treeBlobs is read in from a file, and I can't share that data.  Also the id++ really shouldn't matter because that line is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what throws the exception. Sounds like you're using `alarm` combined with a `$SIG{ALRM}` handler to convert the signal into an exception.

Comment: I'm not throwing an exception.  I'm not actually doing anything with either the alarm method or $SIG{ALRM} (or with Mail::SpamAssassin::Timeout).  Most of the time the alarm ignore is caught by the eval, but sometimes it's not and the script is killed.  I find this lack of consistency to also be very confusing.

Comment: You, your program, a modules you use, whatever. Something is throwing exception `"__alarm__ignore__\n"`. And based on the string, it's probably thrown in response to an `alarm` signal. It's definitely not thrown by the code you posted.